# Removing temporary files created by pdf()

Tags: r, pdf, plot

When storing plots in a pdf R generates a temporary file (e.g. `/tmp/RtmpFKQqjI/pdf317d27df81a0`) for each plot. After drawing many plots into a pdf my */tmp* partition runs out of memory and R stops working (my desktop also freezes).

Little code example:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
    pdf(file=paste(i, ".pdf", sep=""))
    plot(1:10)
    dev.off()
}

list.files(path=tempdir(), pattern="^pdf.", full.names=TRUE)
# [1] "/tmp/RtmpFKQqjI/pdf317d27df81a0" "/tmp/RtmpFKQqjI/pdf317d28ed0612"
# [3] "/tmp/RtmpFKQqjI/pdf317d295c2453" "/tmp/RtmpFKQqjI/pdf317d304bb025"
# [5] "/tmp/RtmpFKQqjI/pdf317d3332d7fe" "/tmp/RtmpFKQqjI/pdf317d3921428f"
# [7] "/tmp/RtmpFKQqjI/pdf317d4cf812ca" "/tmp/RtmpFKQqjI/pdf317d5082bebe"
# [9] "/tmp/RtmpFKQqjI/pdf317d560d326"  "/tmp/RtmpFKQqjI/pdf317d674b25ea"
```

(Same results for `pdf(file="Rplots%03d.pdf"); for (i in 1:10) { ... }; dev.off()`.)

Why doesn't R remove this temporary files after calling `dev.off()`?

As a workaround I add the following line after each `dev.off()`:

```
unlink(list.files(path=tempdir(), pattern="^pdf.", full.names=TRUE))
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: unlink only frees the space if nothing has the file open.  Are you sure they are closed?  Do you have lsof on your system?

Comment: IMHO the files are closed (definitely after calling `dev.off()`). `lsof | grep "/tmp/Rtmp*/pdf*"` returns nothing (`$? == 1`). The unlink workaround works (memory is free afterwards).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tend to agree with @stark that this is a (minor) bug in R's `pdf` device implementation.

One workaround is to instead use the `cairo_pdf` device, which produces essentially identical pdfs but does not leave extra files lying around in the temp directory.

```
for (i in 1:2) {
    cairo_pdf(file=paste(i, ".pdf", sep=""))
    plot(1:10)
    dev.off()
}
list.files(path=tempdir(), pattern="^pdf.", full.names=TRUE)
# character(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your additional workaround. It is better than calling `unlink(...)` after each plot statement.

Answer (score 3):

Since the file is closed after dev.off is called, this is a bug in R's pdf library.  Best solution is to get the bug fixed.  There's no reason for pdf to leave tmp files.

Comment: I wrote a bug report: [Bug 14991](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=14991)